# Excel Macro gives run-time error '1004' every other time

Tags: excel, vba

My macro produces a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" every other time it runs.  The error occurs on ".Add" under cel.Validation.

Originally the code gave the error on every attempt.  After some research I found there can be issues when protection is on, hence the commented out section of the code.

This code check's values on other worksheets and is supposed to set the validation if certain conditions are met.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Table1Check As Range
    Dim Table2Check As Range
    Dim LocalCells As Range
    Dim cellCheck As Range
    Dim cellAddr As String

    Set Table1Check = Worksheets("Table1").Range("A16:AC467")
    Set Table2Check = Worksheets("Table2").Range("A16:AC467")
    Set LocalCells = ActiveSheet.Range("R13:R464")

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "<pw>"
    ActiveSheet.Range("R13:R464").Locked = False
    ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value = False
    'ActiveSheet.EnableOutlining = True
    'ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="<pw>", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True

    For Each cel In LocalCells

        Test0 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column + 1), Table1Check, 16, False)
        cellAddr = ActiveSheet.Cells(cel.Row + 3, cel.Column - 3).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
        Set cellCheck = Worksheets("Table2").Range(cellAddr)

        If Test0 = "Option1" Or Test0 = "Option2" Then
            cel.Interior.Color = xlNone
            cel.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternNone
            If cellCheck.Interior.Pattern <> xlPatternUp Then
                With cel.Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                        Formula1:="A,B"
                End With
            Else
                With cel.Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                        Formula1:="A"
                End With
            End If
        ElseIf cellCheck.Interior.Pattern <> xlPatternUp Then
            cel.Interior.Color = xlNone
            cel.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternNone
            With cel.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                    Formula1:="B"
            End With
        Else
            cel.Interior.Color = xlNone
            cel.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternUp
            cel.Interior.PatternColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            cel.Validation.Delete
        End If



    Next cel

    'ActiveSheet.Unprotect "<pw>"
    ActiveSheet.Range("R13:R464").Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value = True
    ActiveSheet.EnableOutlining = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="<pw>", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True

End Sub
```

Regarding protection, this is how every worksheet is protected upon workbook open:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        ws.EnableOutlining = True

        If ws.Name = "Version" Then
            ws.Protect Password:="<pw>", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True
        Else
            ws.Protect Password:="<pw>", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True
        End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Please forgive my ignorance if this a simple problem (my excel-vba skills are self taught).  I tried searching for other solutions but couldn't find any.  I don't understand why it works every other execution.

UPDATE: I just discovered that if `CommandButton1` is clicked while `CheckBox1` is checked, then the macro fails.  If `CheckBox1` is not checked, then it works.  This explains why it worked every other time, because on a fail my macro didn't complete, therefore it never reached the `ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value = True` line.  So the next time I ran it, the `CheckBox1` was unchecked.  I still don't understand why this happens, because I "uncheck" in the code before the for loop starts: `ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value = False`

Comment: A comment, I'd change `Set LocalCells = ActiveSheet.Range("R13:R464")`  to get rid of `ActiveSheet`, and replace that with the sheet those cells are on, e.g. `Set LocalCells = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R13:R464")`.  It could be because you run it once, and the sheet you expect to get the `LocalCells` from isn't the active one?

Comment: Which cel.Validation  ADD?? There are three, and have different formula-s.  Could that cause this problem?

Comment: @BruceWayne I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: @donPablo it fails on the second .Add, but I suspect that is only because that is the first "ElseIf" check to be evaluated in my data-set.

Comment: @Xaples Are your formulas really `"A"` and `"B"`, or are these substitutes for something else?

Comment: @dwirony they are substitutes.  However, the original is still just text.

Comment: @GMalc that is an excel built in alias for a specific cell pattern.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpattern

Answer (score 0):

Based on my UPDATE I was able to find a solution.  I'm not 100% sure what was happening, but it now works if I comment out these two lines:

```
ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value = False
ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value = True
```

Perhaps it was interfering with my macro, because the `CheckBox1_Click()` code locks/unlocks the `LocalCells` range.  Does changing a check box value activate its click macro?